# How to fix FFMpeg's declared deprecated?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to wirte FFmpeg client side streaming these are some errors occurs

> Error  C4996   'av_register_all': was declared deprecated
>   Error   C4996   'av_free_packet': was declared deprecated
>   Error   C4996   'AVStream::codec': was declared deprecated
>   Error   C4996   'avcodec_decode_video2': was declared deprecated
>   Error   C4996   'avcodec_copy_context': was declared deprecated

```
  int size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
  ccontext>width,ccontext->height);
  uint8_t* picture_buf = (uint8_t*)(av_malloc(size));
  AVFrame* pic = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  AVFrame* picrgb = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  int size2 = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, ccontext->width, 
  ccontext->height);
  uint8_t* picture_buf2 = (uint8_t*)(av_malloc(size2));
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pic, picture_buf, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
  ccontext->width, ccontext->height);
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picrgb, picture_buf2,AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, 
  ccontext->width, ccontext->height);

  while (av_read_frame(context, &packet) >= 0 && cnt < 1000)
 {//read 100 frames

    std::cout << "1 Frame: " << cnt << std::endl;
    if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index) 
    {//packet is video
        std::cout << "2 Is Video" << std::endl;
        if (stream == NULL)
        {//create stream in file
            std::cout << "3 create stream" << std::endl;
            stream = avformat_new_stream(oc, context- 
            >streams[video_stream_index]->codec->codec);
            avcodec_copy_context(stream->codec, context- 
            >streams[video_stream_index]->codec);
            stream->sample_aspect_ratio = context- 
            >streams[video_stream_index]->codec->sample_aspect_ratio;
        }
        int check = 0;
        packet.stream_index = stream->id;
        std::cout << "4 decoding" << std::endl;
        int result = avcodec_decode_video2(ccontext, pic,          
        &check,&packet);
        std::cout << "Bytes decoded " << result << " check " << check << 
        std::endl;
        if (cnt > 100)//cnt < 0)
        {
            sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, pic->data, pic->linesize, 0, 
            ccontext->height, picrgb->data, picrgb->linesize);
            std::stringstream name;
            name << "test" << cnt << ".ppm";
            myfile.open(name.str());
            myfile << "P3 " << ccontext->width << " " << ccontext->height 
                  << " 255\n";
            for (int y = 0; y < ccontext->height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < ccontext->width * 3; x++)
                    myfile << (int)(picrgb-> 
                data[0] + y * picrgb->linesize[0])[x] << " ";
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to look up what those errors mean? Have you read the documentation for the version of ffmpeg you're using?

Comment: Gnoses should be warnings, not errors. Disable the warnings as errors flag when you compile.

Comment: If something is deprecated it means you should stop using it and that there's a new and better alternative. Why don't you just change your code to use the new thing and fix the error that way?

Answer (score 4):

First off, those should be warnings, not errors. If they are errors you compiler settings are set too strict

`av_register_all()` - No longer used [since 2018](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/70d25268c21cbee5f08304da95be1f647c630c15/doc/APIchanges#L86), Just delete this line

`av_free_packet()` -> `av_packet_unref()` [since 2015](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/70d25268c21cbee5f08304da95be1f647c630c15/doc/APIchanges#L642C1-L642C5).

`AVStream::codec` -> `AVStream::codecpar`

`avcodec_decode_video2` -> replace this with the `avcodec_send_packet`, `avcodec_receive_frame` mechanic

and finally:
`avcodec_copy_context` -> From the documentation:

> The semantics of this function are ill-defined and it should not
> be used. If you need to transfer the stream parameters from one codec context
> to another, use an intermediate AVCodecParameters instance and the
> avcodec_parameters_from_context() / avcodec_parameters_to_context()
> functions.