# Problems with outputting stream format as RTMP via FFmpeg C-API

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, mp4, rtmp

I am using FFmpeg's C API to push video streams `rtmp://....` into an [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) server.
The **input stream is an MP4** file named [`juren-30s.mp4`](https://github.com/lokenetwork/FFmpeg-Principle/blob/main/output/juren-30s.mp4). 
The **output stream is also an MP4** file named `juren-30s-5.mp4`.

My piece of code  (see further down) works fine when used in the following steps:
`mp4 -> demux -> decode -> rgb images -> encode -> mux -> mp4`.

**Problem:**

When I changed the output stream to an online RTMP url named `rtmp://ip:port/live/stream_nb_23` (just an example, you can change it according to your server and rules.)

**result:** This code would be corrupted `mp4 -> rtmp(flv)`.

**What I've tried:**

**Changing the output format**
I changed the output format param to become **flv** when I initialized the `avformat_alloc_output_context2`. But this didn't help.

**Debugging the output**
When I executed `ffprobe rtmp://ip:port/live/xxxxxxx`, I got the following errors and did not know why:

```
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] luma_log2_weight_denom 12 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] Missing reference picture, default is 2
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] concealing 8003 DC, 8003 AC, 8003 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] QP 4294966938 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] luma_log2_weight_denom 21 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] luma_log2_weight_denom 10 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] chroma_log2_weight_denom 12 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] QP 4294967066 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] QP 341 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55a925e3ba80] decode_slice_header error
```

I am confused about the difference between **MP4** and **RTMP** of how to use FFmpeg C-API to produce a correct output stream format.

Besides, I also wanna learn how to convert video and audio streams into other formats using FFmpeg C-api, such as `flv`, `ts`, `rtsp`, etc.

**Code to reproduce the problem**:

- I have also put the [project files (code, video files) on Github](https://github.com/lokenetwork/FFmpeg-Principle/tree/main/output).
- The C code shown below can be specifically [found at Main.c](https://github.com/lokenetwork/FFmpeg-Principle/blob/main/output/main.c) which is a minimum version to reproduce. It can be reproduced and run successfully.

So how to make this code output to **RTMP** without getting issue of an unplayable video?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
int main()
{
    int ret = 0; int err;

    //Open input file
    char filename[] = "juren-30s.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!fmt_ctx) {
        printf("error code %d \n",AVERROR(ENOMEM));
        return ENOMEM;
    }
    if((err = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filename,NULL,NULL)) < 0){
        printf("can not open file %d \n",err);
        return err;
    }

    //Open the decoder
    AVCodecContext *avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(avctx, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->codecpar);
    if (ret < 0){
        printf("error code %d \n",ret);
        return ret;
    }
    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(avctx->codec_id);
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        printf("open codec faile %d \n",ret);
        return ret;
    }

    //Open the output file container
    char filename_out[] = "juren-30s-5.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx_out = NULL;
    err = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fmt_ctx_out, NULL, NULL, filename_out);
    if (!fmt_ctx_out) {
        printf("error code %d \n",AVERROR(ENOMEM));
        return ENOMEM;
    }
    //Add all the way to the container context
    AVStream *st = avformat_new_stream(fmt_ctx_out, NULL);
    st->time_base = fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base;

    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx = NULL;
    
    AVPacket *pt = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket *pkt_out = av_packet_alloc();

    int frame_num = 0; int read_end = 0;
    
    for(;;){
        if( 1 == read_end ){ break;}

        ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
        //Skip and do not process audio packets
        if( 1 == pkt->stream_index ){
            av_packet_unref(pt);
            continue;
        }

        if ( AVERROR_EOF == ret) {
            //After reading the file, the data and size of pkt should be null at this time
            avcodec_send_packet(avctx, NULL);
        }else {
            if( 0 != ret){
                printf("read error code %d \n",ret);
                return ENOMEM;
            }else{
                retry:
                if (avcodec_send_packet(avctx, pkt) == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                    printf("Receive_frame and send_packet both returned EAGAIN, which is an API violation.\n");
                    //Here you can consider sleeping for 0.1 seconds and returning EAGAIN. This is usually because there is a bug in ffmpeg's internal API.
                    goto retry;
                }
                //Release the encoded data in pkt
                av_packet_unref(pt);
            }

        }

        //The loop keeps reading data from the decoder until there is no more data to read.
        for(;;){
            //Read AVFrame
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(avctx, frame);
            /* Release the YUV data in the frame,
             * Since av_frame_unref is called in the avcodec_receive_frame function, the following code can be commented.
             * So we don't need to manually unref this AVFrame
             * */
            //off_frame_unref(frame);

            if( AVERROR(EAGAIN) == ret ){
                //Prompt EAGAIN means the decoder needs more AVPackets
                //Jump out of the first layer of for and let the decoder get more AVPackets
                break;
            }else if( AVERROR_EOF == ret ){
                /* The prompt AVERROR_EOF means that an AVPacket with both data and size NULL has been sent to the decoder before.
                 * Sending NULL AVPacket prompts the decoder to flush out all cached frames.
                 * Usually a NULL AVPacket is sent only after reading the input file, or when another video stream needs to be decoded with an existing decoder.
                 *
                 * */

                /* Send null AVFrame to the encoder and let the encoder flush out the remaining data.
                 * */
                ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, NULL);
                for(;;){
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt_out);
                    //It is impossible to return EAGAIN here, if there is any, exit directly.
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)){
                        printf("avcodec_receive_packet error code %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }
                    
                    if ( AVERROR_EOF == ret ){ break; }
                    
                    //Encode the AVPacket, print some information first, and then write it to the file.
                    printf("pkt_out size : %d \n",pkt_out->size);
                    //Set the stream_index of AVPacket so that you know which stream it is.
                    pkt_out->stream_index = st->index;
                    //Convert the time base of AVPacket to the time base of the output stream.
                    pkt_out->pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->pts, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt_out->dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->dts, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt_out->duration = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->duration, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);


                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx_out, pkt_out);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        printf("av_interleaved_write_frame faile %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }
                    av_packet_unref(pt_out);
                }
                av_write_trailer(fmt_ctx_out);
                //Jump out of the second layer of for, the file has been decoded.
                read_end = 1;
                break;
            }else if( ret >= 0 ){
                //Only when a frame is decoded can the encoder be initialized.
                if( NULL == enc_ctx ){
                    //Open the encoder and set encoding information.
                    AVCodec *encode = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
                    enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encode);
                    enc_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
                    enc_ctx->bit_rate = 400000;
                    enc_ctx->framerate = avctx->framerate;
                    enc_ctx->gop_size = 30;
                    enc_ctx->max_b_frames = 10;
                    enc_ctx->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN;
                   
                    /*
                     * In fact, the following information is also available in the container. You can also open the encoder directly in the container at the beginning.
                     * I took these encoder parameters from AVFrame because the difference in the container is final.
                     * Because the AVFrame you decoded may go through a filter, the information will be transformed after the filter, but this article does not use filters.
                     */
                     
                    //The time base of the encoder should be the time base of AVFrame, because AVFrame is the input. The time base of AVFrame is the time base of the stream.
                    enc_ctx->time_base = fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base;
                    enc_ctx->width = fmt_ctx->streams[0]->codecpar->width;
                    enc_ctx->height = fmt_ctx->streams[0]->codecpar->height;
                    enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = st->sample_aspect_ratio = frame->sample_aspect_ratio;
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = frame->format;
                    enc_ctx->color_range            = frame->color_range;
                    enc_ctx->color_primaries        = frame->color_primaries;
                    enc_ctx->color_trc              = frame->color_trc;
                    enc_ctx->colorspace             = frame->colorspace;
                    enc_ctx->chroma_sample_location = frame->chroma_location;

                    /* Note that the value of this field_order is different for different videos. I have written it here.
                     * Because the video in this article is AV_FIELD_PROGRESSIVE
                     * The production environment needs to process different videos
                     */
                    enc_ctx->field_order = AV_FIELD_PROGRESSIVE;

                    /* Now we need to copy the encoder parameters to the stream. When decoding, assign parameters from the stream to the decoder.
                     * Now let’s do it in reverse.
                     * */
                    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(st->codecpar,enc_ctx);
                    if (ret < 0){
                        printf("error code %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }
                    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encode, NULL)) < 0) {
                        printf("open codec faile %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }

                    //Formally open the output file
                    if ((ret = avio_open2(&fmt_ctx_out->pb, filename_out, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE,&fmt_ctx_out->interrupt_callback,NULL)) < 0) {
                        printf("avio_open2 fail %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }

                    //Write the file header first.
                    ret = avformat_write_header(fmt_ctx_out,NULL);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        printf("avformat_write_header fail %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }

                }

                //Send AVFrame to the encoder, and then continuously read AVPacket
                ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    printf("avcodec_send_frame fail %d \n",ret);
                    return ret;
                }
                for(;;){
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt_out);
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)){ break; }
                    
                    if (ret < 0){
                    printf("avcodec_receive_packet fail %d \n",ret);
                    return ret;
                    }
                    
                    //Encode the AVPacket, print some information first, and then write it to the file.
                    printf("pkt_out size : %d \n",pkt_out->size);

                    //Set the stream_index of AVPacket so that you know which stream it is.
                    pkt_out->stream_index = st->index;
                    
                    //Convert the time base of AVPacket to the time base of the output stream.
                    pkt_out->pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->pts, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt_out->dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->dts, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt_out->duration = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt_out->duration, fmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base, st->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);

                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx_out, pkt_out);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        printf("av_interleaved_write_frame faile %d \n",ret);
                        return ret;
                    }
                    av_packet_unref(pt_out);
                }

            }
            else{ printf("other fail \n"); return ret;}
        }
    }
    
    av_frame_free(&frame); av_packet_free(&pt); av_packet_free(&pkt_out);
    
    //Close the encoder and decoder.
    avcodec_close(avctx); avcodec_close(enc_ctx);

    //Release container memory.
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);

    //Must adjust avio_closep, otherwise the data may not be written in, it will be 0kb
    avio_closep(&fmt_ctx_out->pb);
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx_out);
    printf("done \n");

    return 0;
}
```

This problem has haunted over my head for about three weeks. I still have no idea where the key bug exists. Really appreciate it if any FFmpeg expert could help me.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: While you wait (I do not use FFmp eg with C++, only in commandline)... **(1)** If you open your link `rtmp://ip:port/live/xxxxxxx` with [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) then do you see a picture? Also what does **Codec Details** (in VLC options) say about the incoming RTMP's video codec? **(2)** Is there anyway for you to save one of these RTMP packets and show us a file link? Sometimes checking the file bytes alone can help others to see what's wrong with your output content.

Comment: I can not see a picture. Because I think the key problem lies in configuring the header of RTMP packet correctly. But I have no idea how to configure it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. It involves with the sequence of steps when pushing an online stream.

correct sequence:

```
find encoder -> encoder context (set encoder params)-> allocate packet/frame -> format context &streams.
```

Answer (score 2):

The example from [leixiaohua1020](https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/blob/master/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer/simplest_ffmpeg_streamer.cpp)'s Github uses a bit different transmission and closure schema:

[image]

The timecode rescaler is invoked also in a different way:

```cpp
/* copy packet */
        //Convert PTS/DTS
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;
```

to obtain proper handling of H.264 streams.

I guess, you should also copy entire `AVFormatContext` with the function

```cpp
// this function has already not recommended in ffmpeg
avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec);
```

instead of copying parameters to get the proper header, or to use intermediate `AVCodecContext` instance as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57187224/9560245)

Comment: thx，I will take a try

Comment: I tried but failed. for many cases I use ffmpeg, the input video stream is not `flv` format, so purly copying the input context does not help. But also codec params is located in `stream->codecpar`, not `stream->codec`

Comment: Did you try something like this? https://github.com/avaer/ffmpeg-rtmp/blob/master/example.c

The stream parameters are literally differing from the MP4 import parameters.

Comment: I decided to learn examples provided by ffmpeg, those codes is effective, and seems does not designate specific params.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. When I push an RTMP stream using the FFmpeg command line, there is no problem.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "sample.mp4" -f flv rtmp://sample.url.com/livestream
```

However, when I use the C API to push the stream, the rtmp server cannot resolve the stream and always return "-32" which means "Broken pipe". The process of my code is as follows:

```
mp4 -> demuxing -> AVFrame -> muxing -> flv --- RTMP ---> RTMP server
```

It turns out that the core of this problem is that I did not set a separate header file for the flv stream.

Finally, it works.
Setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVFormatContext->flags` does not work. This results that `AVStream->codecpar->extradata` will be NULL. This actually causes pipe broken.
Setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVCodecContext->flags` solves the problem, but it should be executed before opening the encoder.

The key of the code like:

```
setting the AVCodecContext...

if (FormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER){
       AVCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

avcodec_open2(AVCodecContext, AVCodec, NULL);
```

The solution can also be found out in ffmpeg/doc/examples/muxing.c.

Overall, the problem appears when some output formats want stream headers to be separate and it can be solved by setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` to `AVCodecContext->flags`